# What is the difference between developer.paypal.com and x.com?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I thought that I have a developer account at PayPal (still logging in successfully to https://developer.paypal.com), but when clicked the [PayPal Developer Network](https://www.x.com/) link on that page (to ask a question that's specific to PayPal API), I was prompted to login again. This time, my developer.paypal.com's account userid & password simply wouldn't work there.

Am I supposed to create **another** account there? If so, will it be linked to the developer.paypal.com one (just as accounts in SO/SE are linked)?

If I may explain my confusion further: I have a "regular" PayPal account (for purchasing stuff online), I have a business account (for accepting online payments), I have a developer account (for testing integration of shopping cart with paypal). How many accounts do I need with PayPal? When I create an x.com account, will it conflict with my existing accounts?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: What's even more confusing is the question in the login page to x.com:

> Already have a PayPal account?

Well, of course I have **a** PayPal account. In fact, I have 3 of them. Do I need to create *another* one, just to post a question in the developer network forum?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't need to create another account. To login to the `PayPal Developer Network`, you can use either your personal or business PayPal account, but (ironically) not the "developer account".

The https://developer.paypal.com site is for the **sandbox** only. The https://www.x.com/ site is the actual PayPal Developer Network (tools, API, forums, support, etc.).

Notice the announcement on sandbox homepage:

> PayPal Developer Central is moving to
>   x.com